# Not able to convert txt2tags file using pandoc

Tags: haskell, pandoc, txt2tags

The pandoc information page lists txt2tags as one of the file formats that it can read and use: http://pandoc.org/

I am trying following command to convert a t2t file:

```
$ pandoc article.t2t -f txt2tags -t html -s -o article.html
```

But I get following error:

```
pandoc: Unknown reader: txt2tags
```

Same error comes if I try `-f t2t` rather than `-f txt2tags`.

I found [this site for reader](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-1.19.2.1/docs/Text-Pandoc-Readers-Txt2Tags.html) but how do I install it? It is not there in Stable Debian repository. Thanks for your help.

Comment: According to the [Pandoc User's Guide](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#general-options), the option for the txt2tags format is `t2t`, and not `txt2tags`.

Comment: That is also showing same error. I had tried that too.

Comment: txt2tags support was added in Pandoc 1.13, released in August 2014 (cf. [that version's changelog](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-1.13/changelog)), while Debian Stable [currently carries 1.12.4](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/pandoc). (The latest version of Pandoc, by the way, is 1.19.2.1.)

Comment: How can I install the latest version?

Comment: As mentioned by the [Installing page in Pandoc's site](http://pandoc.org/installing.html), you can get an updated .deb from [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/1.19.2.1).

Comment: Are there many dependencies? You should enter all this information as an answer.

Comment: "Are there many dependencies?" -- Probably no more than for the regular Debian Stable package.